# I need a solution to this SQL Query I'm trying to solve

Tags: sql, data-analysis

> "Write a query that determines the customer that has spent the most on
>   music for each country. Write a query that returns the country along
>   with the top customer and how much they spent. For countries where the
>   top amount spent is shared, provide all customers who spent this
>   amount.
>
> You should only need to use the Customer and Invoice tables.
>
> Check Your Solution
>
> Though there are only 24 countries, your query should return 25 rows
>   because the United Kingdom has 2 customers that share the maximum."

You can find the data set here

[image: Data Table].

Here is the code I tried with the results

[image: Query Trial]

And here is the expected outcome

[image: Expected Results]

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you should always `GROUP BY` anything in your `SELECT` that is not an aggregation function (e.g. `SUM`). Try this:

```
SELECT c.CustomerId, c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.Country,
       SUM(i.Total) AS TotalSpent
FROM Customer c
JOIN Invoice i
ON i.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
GROUP BY c.CustomerId, c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.Country
ORDER BY c.Country
```

Comment: Thank you, but what I tried was just a part of the answer, here's the full answer in case someone needs it:
WITH tab1 AS 
(
 SELECT c.CustomerId, c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.Country, SUM(i.Total) TotalSpent
 FROM Customer c
 JOIN Invoice i ON c.CustomerId = i.CustomerId
 GROUP BY c.CustomerId
)
SELECT tab1.*
FROM tab1
JOIN
(
 SELECT CustomerId, FirstName, LastName, Country, MAX(TotalSpent) AS TotalSpent
 FROM tab1
 GROUP BY Country
) tab2
ON tab1.Country = tab2.Country
WHERE tab1.TotalSpent = tab2.TotalSpent
ORDER BY Country;

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH tab1 AS ( SELECT c.CustomerId, c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.Country, SUM(i.Total) TotalSpent FROM Customer c JOIN Invoice i ON c.CustomerId = i.CustomerId GROUP BY c.CustomerId ) SELECT tab1.* FROM tab1 left JOIN ( SELECT CustomerId, FirstName, LastName, Country, MAX(TotalSpent) AS TotalSpent FROM tab1 GROUP BY Country ) tab2 ON tab1.Country = tab2.Country WHERE tab1.TotalSpent = tab2.TotalSpent ORDER BY Country;
```

Comment: While an SQL is all the OP has asked for, it would be helpful for him and for others if you left a comment that would help us to understand this big, long select

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here
select concat(c.first_name," ",c.last_name) as 
top_customer,c.country,pl.name,round(sum(i.total),2)as sum_total
from customer c 
join invoice i on c.customer_id=i.customer_id
join invoice_line il on il.invoice_id=i.invoice_id
join playlist_track pt on pt.track_id=il.track_id
join playlist pl on pl.playlist_id=pt.playlist_id
where pl.name like "music"
group by 1,2,3
order by sum_total desc;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).